# Can Spring Cloud Dataflow running on Pivotal Cloud Foundry write files to an on prem server?

Tags: architecture, spring-cloud-stream, cloud-foundry, spring-cloud-dataflow

I have been off and on experimenting with Spring Dataflow for the past few months. I have been running dataflow on my own computer using a Docker container. I have some use cases that either grab a file from an FTP site and write it to an on-premises file share, or write a file from an on-premises fileshare up to an FTP site. It seemed like Dataflow would be a great solution for this.

My company is moving to Pivotal Cloud Foundry and the thought was to run Dataflow on it. I was recently told that PCF has no easy way of writing files to my on-prem servers. Is there a way to mount a volume, similar to what you have to do with docker so that I can make use of the out of the box File Source and Sink apps that come with Dataflow?

Comment: https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/services/using-vol-services.html?

Comment: Looks like what I would want except I am trying to write my file to a windows file system.

Comment: Then I guess that also answers your question. If you're using a Windows cell, that's not supported.

Comment: Dataflow provides out of the box source apps for s/ftp that upload files to a local drive. For cloud foundry you must use volume services as previously suggested. There may be a way to nfs mount a Windows share to use with volume services but seems like it would be failure prone if it works at all. Have you considered using S3?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use Volume Services. If you deploy Spring Cloud DataFlow to Pivotal Cloud Foundry, everything that gets deployed by SCDF will be Java apps and those will all be running in Linux Cells. Linux Cells support both NFS & SMB Volume Service drivers.

If your source and/or target servers are Windows servers, that's fine too. You would simply need to use the SMB Volume Service, since NFS isn't going to work with Windows. See the following document to make sure that SMB Volume Services is enabled.

https://docs.pivotal.io/platform/application-service/operating/enable-vol-services.html#smb-enable

Then, you should be able to mount Windows volumes to your apps using the following instructions.

https://docs.pivotal.io/pivotalcf/devguide/services/using-vol-services.html#smb